# How are pressure, force, thrust related?

Tags: forces, pressure, dimensional-analysis, rocket-science, propulsion

we know that Thrust  = Pressure × Area and pressure is force/area. So we substitute pressure in the thrust formula and we get: Thrust= Force/Area*Area. Which simplifies to Thrust = Force. So is Force same as thrust?

Comment: As a warning, I notice that within a time of less than a day you have now asked a total of *six* near-identical questions, mostly ignoring comments and answers you have already received on all of them. This behavior comes dangerously close to what we call "spamming", and may get you banned if it continues.

Answer (score 1):

> **So is Force same as thrust?**

Yes, thrust is just another name for force. It is used in the context of aircraft and rocket engines for example. These vehicles have other forces acting on them, so it is useful to have separate names for different forces. Lift, drag and gravity are also forces that act on those vehicles.

Comment: So according to the formula I mentioned, can we say that: Thrust is directly proportional to the pressure and also Thrust is directly proportional to the Area?

Comment: One question per question please. If you want a discussion, this Q&A site is unsuitable for that.

Comment: What pressure? What area? In this and other questions of yours the issue is that you are throwing random quantities into equations they don't belong. As an only slightly exaggerated analogy, what you are doing is like saying "force is equal to area times pressure, so thrust is equal to the product of the pressure exerted by the seat of my pants on the chair I'm sitting on, times the surface area of a sack of rice in China".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to clarify the difference between force and thrust right now.

In thrust there is a internal reaction such as in Jet engines or rocket engines which causes force. This is what we know as "Thrust". Force in otherhand, is caused by external reactions such as pushing a chair.

Also Thrust is the total force acting perpendicular to the surface. The unit of thrust is Newton. The force acting over unit area is called pressure. The unit of pressure in the SI system is Newton/m2.

Correct me if I am wrong but according to me thrust is the force generated in the opposite direction of the exhaust gases. So force and thrust have velocity in opposite direction and both are vectors. If thrust is 5 newtons north then the force will be 5 newtons south. Please tell me if I am right.

Comment: No. "Thrust" is just another name for "force". A thrust of "5 newtons north" means you'll have a force of "5 newtons north".