# Interpretation of the formula of Thrust

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, rocket-science, propulsion

According to the formula Thrust= Pressure x Area, can we say that: Thrust is directly proportional to the pressure and also Thrust is directly proportional to the Area?

Comment: That is literally the definition of thrust: $Thrust = Pressure \times Area$.  It's directly proportional to pressure and to area because pressure times area are what make it...

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308806/2451

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, since thrust is a force, and F = P x A, force (said thrust in this case) is directly proportional to both pressure and area.

Comment: You should be more clear in your answer. Thrust is not just a mere force, it is the perpendicular force to a surface. A plane can direct the force downwards instead of pusing itself, there is a force but the thrust is zero.