# Relation between density and thrust

Tags: astrophysics

Now lets look at the larger picture or lets try to put the pieces together.

Is thrust dependent on air density?
Yes, Thrust is dependent on the density of air. Thrust is the force of flight that pushes in the direction of the aircraft’s motion. By Newton’s second law, the force needed to accelerate an object increases with the object’s mass. The greater the density of the fluid, the greater its mass. A greater density means a greater mass, and a greater mass means a greater force. Thus, the amount of thrust generated must increase when the fluid density increases.

http://howthingsfly.si.edu/ask-an-explainer/thrust-dependent-air-density

Now in most cases density of the exhaust gases in the rocket is less dense than the air outside. So this formula which says that Thrust= pressure x Area. This means the thrust is proportional to area. So if a gas in the exhaust is less dense and occupies more area then this will also increase the thrust if I go as per the formula. But I am not sure of this. So I need help.

Comment: Boyle's law is a gas law, stating that the pressure and volume of a gas have an inverse relationship, when temperature is held constant. If volume increases, then pressure decreases and vice versa, when temperature is held constant. So a dense gas will have less volume and so since volume decreases pressure increases. If pressure increases thrust also increases. This also proves the above that greater density greater thrust. Is this correct? Kindly answer this question also. Thank you physics stackexchange.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308806/2451

Comment: No, this is not correct.

Answer (score -2):

I think I have the answer.  If a gas in the exhaust is less dense and occupies more area then this will also increase the thrust. Now the area we are talking about is the area of the nozzle. The area of the nozzle is more so ideally according to the formula thrust will be more.

The larger the nozzle's cross-section at the exit, the higher the speed and the lower the pressure that the gas can achieve at the exit. For optimum thrust the gas pressure at the nozzle exit should be exactly equal to the outside air pressure.

So according to the formula Thrust= pressure x Area of the nozzle. So bigger the area of the nozzle the greater is the thrust. Also  the faster the gas produced can escape the engine, the greater the upward thrust of the rocket.

Comment: No, you have no cogent concept of how rocket engines work. Specifically your original idea of thrust being related to air density makes no sense. The [Wikipedia article on rocket engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine) has a lot of material that might help get you started.

Comment: You seem to be equating things in situations where  they don't apply.  Your analysis is trying to over-simplify a fairly complicated process; and you're using equations well outside where they are applicable.